# ng-grid selectRow is undefined when setting rowTemplate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

When I set the rowTemplate on the ngGrid options, all rows selection functions, such as selectRow becomes undefined.
This is really strange.

For example look here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/m4GZftllwZzjYkEvXo3u?p=preview

```
// main.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];




    $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
    $scope.gridOptions.rowTemplate = 'rowTemplate';

    setTimeout(function(){
                $scope.gridOptions.selectRow(3, true);
            },0);
});
```

Selecting a row throws undefined exception.
Remove the "rowTemplate" from the ngOptions - and you got this working!

Anyone encountered this?

Comment: not related to your problem, but use $timeout instead of setTimeout

Comment: Yes, you are right. Although this of course doesn't solve this issue ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.
Strangely enough, you need to increase the timeout (above 1000) to make it work.
Really strange.

Comment: This is, of course, not a very good solution. Better one is to listen to ngGridEventData, and inside use $timeout to select a row. Works.